Fullscreen detection with Ruffle
I've been working on a function that got some kind of addEventListener each time the browser is in fullscreen (F11). When this happens, the Ruffle Player enters in Fullscreen at the same time, and when I exit, Ruffle Player also exits. Something like this:
if((window.fullScreen) || (window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height)) {
 window.RufflePlayer.enterFullscreen();
} else {
 window.RufflePlayer.exitFullscreen();
}

Is there any better way to do this?
I tried an if function that detects if the browser is in fullscreen, if true, RufflePlayer enters in fullscreen, else, it exits. This didn't worked.

window.fullScreen or document.fullScreen is no longer recommended and deprecated.
you should use window.fullscreenElement to detect fullscreen or not and for fullscreen change event add a event listener for fullscreenchange 
function Fullscreen(event) {

  if (document.fullscreenElement) {
    window.RufflePlayer.enterFullscreen();
  } else {
    window.RufflePlayer.exitFullscreen();
  }

}

document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", fullscreenchanged);

